# Referencing a class in CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have just created a Jumbotron in CSS linked to Bootstrap

**html code**

```
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
       <div class="title">
           <h1>My Title</h1>
       </div>
        <div class="subtitle">
            <p>My Subtitle</p>
        </div>
    </div>    
  </div>
```

How do I reference the .title class and the .subtitle class in CSS?

I tried in **CSS code**:

```
.title{}

.container .title{}

.jumbotron .container .title{}
```

but anything I do does not reference it.

I want to create a block around the specific pieces of text H1 and P so I can put a faded background behind the text.

---

Edit:

The styling I am trying to include:

```
   .title
{
    top:250px;
    left:140px;
    width:500px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:black;
    z-index:0;
    opacity:0.5;
}
```

I don't want the H1 tag to become opaque too.

Comment: All of those selectors will match the title div.

Comment: Is the CSS you're writing before or after Bootstrap's CSS? You need your CSS to occur after it so that it takes precedence.

Comment: It's after Bootstrap CSS so my code should take precedence

Comment: Maybe you should target the H1 tag, you are only selecting the outer div. The H1 tag will have specific properties that override "general" properties.

Comment: If I target H1 tag then putting a faded background will affect the H1 text too no?

Comment: Include the actual styling you are trying to do.

Comment: The problem may be that you're just not writing a more specific rule than what is specified in Bootstrap, or somewhere else, so your rules get overwritten.

Comment: Targeting the containing div should work; something else is wrong. Still, seeing if targeting H1 works might tell us something.

Comment: There's not enough code here for us to reproduce the problem. Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: When I put what you've got in a JSFiddle that includes Bootstrap, it works.

Comment: I just checked the html <link>  order - my bootstrap link was below the CSS so it was taking precedence! - I thought It was most important run first not the other way round

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your CSS to overwrite or take precedence over styles provided in bootstrap.css, your styles need to occur after bootstrap.css.

For additional information, [W3 Documentation on Assigning property values, Cascading, and Inheritance](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html)

Comment: Thanks for the informative link! That will surely be helpful!

Answer (score -1):

If your question is

> How do I reference the .title class and the .subtitle class in CSS?

The answer is that you are doing it correctly.
If your question is:

> why is it not being seen?

You need to inspect element to make sure that the style is there. If it is then look for the style that is overriding it and copy the exact selector being used and use that for reference

Answer (score -4):

This seems all correct. The examples that you have provided will all reference that title class. Try inspecting element to see if the style is coming through. If the style is not coming through then maybe your style tag is not being seen somehow.

Comment: This should be posted as a comment, not an answer

Comment: I'm sorry, but I believe that I am providing an answer. His answer is that the style is not being seen. He also wanted to make sure that his class references were correct, & I assured him that they were.